# Incremental network loader Error - Geometric netwotk QA

Tags: arcgis-10.1, esri-geodatabase, geometric-network

Trying to merge 2 geometric networks with [Incremental network loader](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/localgovernment/10.1/index.html#//028s000000p1000000) I got this error -[image: error picture]

How can I find this Closed polylines at my geometric network ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A polyline is closed if from and to points are the same. So you could test this in a new field:

field calculator : Python

codeblock

```
def IsClosed(shp):
    if (shp.firstpoint.x == shp.lastpoint.x) and (shp.firstpoint.y == shp.lastpoint.y) :
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

result

```
IsClosed(!Shape!)
```